Eager Loading Child Records with Specific Condition
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :description_hoge_projects, -> { where(description: "hoge") }, class_name: "Project"
end

users = User.preload(:description_hoge_projects)
users.flat_map(&:description_hoge_projects).map(&:description)
=> ["hoge", "hoge", "hoge", "hoge", "hoge", "hoge", "hoge", "hoge", "hoge", "hoge"]

I would like to get all User records, but the Project records associated with the User records should be the ones whose descriptions are "hoge".
I know I can achieve it with the code above, but I would like to do the same thing without using has_many.
It is possible to do it with preload, joins, eager_load and so on?

You can query eager loaded associations (via includes) same way you can with joins:
User.includes(:projects).where(projects: {description: "hoge"})


I appreciate for your answer.
it does not return all User records.
It only returns User records having Post records whose names are "hoge".
User.count => 3
User.includes(:projects).where(projects: { description: "hoge" }).count => 1

So you want to return all users, but just eager load the projects with description: "hoge"? AFAIK, you wouldn't be able to do this without an association. You could eager load all the projects User.includes(:projects) then select the hoge projects when iterating over the users hoge_project = user.projects.select { |p| p.description == "hoge" }, which would still take advantage of the eager loading, but might not be the most efficient.
